# Maven deploy to JFrog Artifactory using access token

Tags: maven, artifactory

I've seen a lot of examples of how to configure Maven to upload using a username / password, but I haven't seen any examples of how to do this using the access token. (Access tokens: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens)

In the examples I've found, the username/password are stored in `settings.xml`. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to use this token with `mvn deploy`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The access token can be used as the password. For example, if your username is `"myuser"` and you have an access token for this user: `"eyHFdghgHDFGHdgdfg5t..."`, then your settings file should have the following:

```
<username>myuser</username>
<password>eyHFdghgHDFGHdgdfg5t...</password>
```

This is basically already covered in the [Using Tokens](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens#AccessTokens-UsingTokens) section of the Wiki you mentioned.

HTH,
Yinon.